# What material blocks cigarette smoke the smell and the vocs from passing through vents?

Tags: vent, smell

I tried blocking the weed/cigarette smoke from neighbors apartment from getting into mine. I've done everything from wrapping kitchen and bathroom vents in aluminium foil, packed and sealed off whole bedroom closet with huge hole in the back for water heater pump with packing tape on the front, leave 2 huge standing fans on which face the apartment door to the hallway, and leave 2 air purifiers running, one with plasmawave and carbon pellets and the other a homemade 20 inch box fan with number 11 filete filter which always sits in front of cracked window no matter what the temperature is outside. Still can smell it getting into my place especially through kitchen vent and bathroom. Does anybody know what I could use or buy that I can wrap around or tape to the vents or can atleast add to it, that will block the cigarette smoke? Plastic wrap, wax paper, cardboard or anything?

Comment: Does each apartment have it’s own thermostat? Does each kitchen and bath exhaust have controls in each unit and controlled separately?

Comment: pressurize your apartment